# SQL - JOIN AN AGGREGATE TABLE WITH A NONAGGREGATE TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, aggregate-functions

I have written the following code that selects the aggregate remaining interest payments from each loan:

> ```
> SELECT
> a.PARENTREF,
> a.INTEREST - Isnull(b.INTEREST,0) AS INTEREST
>
> FROM
> (SELECT 
> PARENTREF,
> SUM(TOTAL) AS INTEREST
>    FROM LG_011_BNCREPAYTR 
>    WHERE TRANSTYPE = 0 
>    GROUP BY PARENTREF) a LEFT OUTER JOIN
> (SELECT
> PARENTREF,
> SUM(TOTAL) AS INTEREST
>    FROM LG_011_BNCREPAYTR 
>    WHERE TRANSTYPE = 1 
>    GROUP BY PARENTREF) b
> ON a.PARENTREF = b.PARENTREF
> ```

It brings a table like the following:

> ```
> PARENTREF       INTEREST
>         1         500.93
>         2         510.00
>         3        1200.90
>         4         500.93
> ```

Now, there is another table in the database that holds other info regarding the loans like the loan description. The `LOGICALREF` of that table is the `PARENTREF` in this table. That table is as follows:

> ```
>  LOGICALREF         DESCRIPTION        CURRENCYREF           DUEDATE
>           1            CAR LOAN                  0        2015-10-01
>           2       CONSUMER LOAN                  2        2015-10-01
>           3            CAR LOAN                  4        2015-10-01
>           4            CAR LOAN                  3        2015-10-01
> ```

I am trying to combine my table with the last table that I mentioned, but for some reason I get the `DESCRIPTION`, `CURRENCYREF` and the `DUEDATE` as `NULL`. I think there is something wrong due to the `GROUP BY` that I am using because if I don't aggregate, these functions work. The table that I want is the following:

> ```
> PARENTREF       INTEREST          DESCRIPTION     CURRENCYREF       DUEDATE 
>         1         500.93             CAR LOAN               0    2015-10-01
>         2         510.00        CONSUMER LOAN               2    2015-10-01
>         3        1200.90             CAR LOAN               4    2015-10-01
>         4         500.93             CAR LOAN               3    2015-10-01
> ```

THANKS A LOT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.PARENTREF, a.INTEREST - ISNULL(b.INTEREST, 0) AS INTEREST, 
       T.DESCRIPTION, T.CURRENCYREF, T.DUEDATE 
FROM YourTable T 
INNER JOIN (SELECT PARENTREF, SUM(TOTAL) AS INTEREST
            FROM LG_011_BNCREPAYTR 
            WHERE TRANSTYPE = 0 
            GROUP BY PARENTREF) A ON T.LOGICALREF = A.PARENTREF
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT PARENTREF, SUM(TOTAL) AS INTEREST
                 FROM LG_011_BNCREPAYTR 
                 WHERE TRANSTYPE = 1 
                 GROUP BY PARENTREF
                ) b ON a.PARENTREF = b.PARENTREF;
```

**OR**

You can also find solution using below query

```
SELECT A.PARENTREF, 
      (SUM(CASE WHEN A.TRANSTYPE = 0 THEN A.TOTAL ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN A.TRANSTYPE = 1 THEN A.TOTAL ELSE 0 END)) AS INTEREST, 
       T.DESCRIPTION, T.CURRENCYREF, T.DUEDATE 
FROM YourTable T 
INNER JOIN LG_011_BNCREPAYTR A ON T.LOGICALREF = A.PARENTREF 
GROUP BY A.PARENTREF;
```